# imread works in Spyder but not in VS Code

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, imread

Why is `imread` working in Anaconda Spyder but producing `None` in Anaconda VS Code?

1. Uninstalled VS Code and reinstalled.
2. Disabled the Microsoft python extension in the hope the Anaconda extension would be used.
3. Checked the CV2 installation with `cv2.GetBuildINformation()`
4. Checked the current path was still the same in VS Code with

```
import os 
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

import cv2
import numpy as np
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())

import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(dir_path)

img = cv2.imread("faces.jpg",1)
print(img)
```

The img is printing as `None` - but only in VS Code.

The path is printing fine. 
The python Version is 3.6.4.

`cv2.getBuildInformation()` returns:

`General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.2 =====================================`
and more info that I have removed due to clutter.

Any helpful suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: I just put this code in a code block and it's being rendered as unformatted text again.

Comment: The path printed out the same in both IDEs? What about the cv2 information?
Try to add a simple check for if the file `faces.jpg` exists and run in both IDEs:
`os.path.isfile(filepath)`

Comment: d:\Documents\Dropbox\Machine Learning\OpenCV in VS Code and d:\Documents\Dropbox\Machine Learning\OpenCV in Spyder... print("file is file ? " + str(os.path.isfile("faces.jpg"))) returns False in Visual Studio Code but True in Spyder!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem is with the configurations of the working directory in the two IDEs. Since, we know that VS Code doesn't see the `faces.jpg` you can just provide it with a full path to the file and check if this is working.

You can check for the current working directory by using `os.getcwd()` and then adjusting the relative path to `faces.jpg` accordingly.

Comment: Yes that's true. Thank you. I'm just not understanding why or how to make VS Studio work with relative paths.

Comment: Shall I rename the question?

Comment: @LindsayFowler, I am using PyCharm and not VS Code, but I am familiar with such problems, since I use Spyder as well. If the structure of the project directories is the same it is the configurations of the working directory in settings.
When you use the path generated by `os` you do not depend on this settings anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In response to Tim Mironov I rewrote my code using the os library to generate paths and this seems to be more robust as it works fine in both IDEs now:

```
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
image_path = os.path.join(dir_path, "faces.jpg")
img = cv2.imread(image_path,1)
```

Now why does VS Studio not find files only sometimes? Well it's to do with **File>Open Folder** versus **File>Open File**

If you open a folder then that folder becomes your current working directory --even if you open another seperate file from another folder which is what I happened to do on this occasion... pretty unlikely but bound to happen to someone else.

You can add a configuration for your file to pursuade Python to use any folder you like. Just Add Debug Configuration and edit launch.json

Documentation from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options will help anyone a bit sketchy on doing this. The behaviour outlined above is explained here:

"cwd
Specifies the current working directory for the debugger, which is the base folder for any relative paths used in code. **If omitted, defaults to ${workspaceFolder} (the folder open in VS Code).**"

Instead of the default option ${workspaceFolder}, use **${fileDirname}** in VS Code's launch.json file to set your current working directory to the folder of your currently executing Python script:

```
{
    "name": "your_program.py",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
```